# Method for calculating Full House not working

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

Here's my code for calculating a full house using 5 die. Now some numbers will work, such as if I roll a 1, 6, 6, 6, 1. But if I roll a 4, 4, 5, 5, 4. It will not work, and I have no idea. I know there is a lot of if statements and it could have done better, but I am a beginner programmer, and this is what I feel comfortable doing since I can't do a complex, logical algorithm. Thanks.

```
        Arrays.sort(die);
        int score = 0;

        int d1 = die[0];
        int d2 = die[1];
        int d3 = die[2];
        int d4 = die[3];
        int d5 = die[4];


        if (d1 == 1)
        {
            if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1)
            {
                if (d3 == 2 && d4 == 2 && d5 == 2)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 3 && d4 == 3 && d5 == 3)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 4 && d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 5 && d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 6 && d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
            else if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1 && d3 == 1)
            {
                if (d4 == 2 && d5 == 2)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 3 && d5 == 3)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
        }
        if (d1 == 2)
        {
            if (d1 == 2 && d2 == 2)
            {
                if (d3 == 3 && d4 == 3 && d5 == 3)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 4 && d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 5 && d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 6 && d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
            else if (d1 == 2 && d2 == 2 && d3 == 2)
            {
                if (d4 == 3 && d5 == 3)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }   
            }
        }
        if (d1 == 3)
        {
            if (d1 == 3 && d2 == 3)
            {
                if (d3 == 4 && d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 5 && d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 6 && d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
            else if (d1 == 3 && d2 == 3 && d3 == 3)
            {
                if (d4 == 4 && d5 == 4)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
        }
        if (d1 == 4)
        {
            if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 4)
            {
                if (d3 == 5 && d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d3 == 6 && d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
            else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 4 && d3 == 4)
            {
                if (d4 == 5 && d5 == 5)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
                if (d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
        }
        if (d1 == 5)
        {
            if (d1 == 5 && d2 == 5)
            {
                if (d3 == 6 && d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
            else if (d1 == 5 && d2 == 5 && d3 == 5)
            {
                if (d4 == 6 && d5 == 6)
                {
                    score = 25;
                }
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly — the reason that { 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 } doesn't work is that this structure:

```
    if (d1 == 4)
    {
        if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 4)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (d1 == 4 && d2 == 4 && d3 == 4)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

will never run the second `...`: the second condition is only ever satisfied in cases where the first condition was already satisfied.

The minimal fix would be to re-order those two `if`-blocks.

A better fix is, don't compare all these dice to fixed values, but rather, compare them to each other. You've already got `Arrays.sort(die)`, which is a good idea. Once you've done that, you can detect a full house just by writing:

```
if (d1 == d5)
{
     // five of a kind
}
else if ((d1 == d2 && d3 == d5) || (d1 == d3 && d4 == d5))
{
     // full house
}
```

Do you see why?

Comment: I think I understand. So as long as d1 != d5, you can use the else if to check if full house?

Comment: @Castellanos: Yes; the `d1 == d5` check ensures that there are (at least) two distinct die values, and the `(d1 == d2 && d3 == d5) || (d1 == d3 && d4 == d5)` check determines whether we have either {a,a,b,b,b} or {a,a,a,b,b} (the two types of full house, provided that *a* and *b* are distinct). And -- you're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

```
Arrays.sort(die);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i : die) {
    set.add(i);
}
boolean isFullHouse = (set.size() == 2) && (die[0] == die[1]) && (die[3] == die[4]);
```

`isFullHouse` will be `true` if you only exactly 2 different numbers, and in the sorted array the first equals the second and the second last is the same as the last.

This avoids all of your `if`s and is not a complex, logical algorithm, it's an easy logical algorithm.

Comment: I agree with your solution, but it is not necessary to test die[0] == die[1] and die[3] == die[4]. If set.size() == 2, then the rest will always be true. Don't you agree?

Comment: We haven't learned about HashSets yet, so I would feel uncomfortable using one. Thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DiogoSantana: No, think about 1,1,1,1,6. `set.size() == 2`, but it's **not** full house.

Comment: Sounds like the job of a multiset like guava's

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff: Although i'm a big guava fan, I don't see how a `MultiMap` could improve the code to check if a `int[]` represents a full house.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly missing cases by checking all dice values like you are doing.

Here's what I would do:

Take the first value and count how many of your dice are equal to that value.
If there is a second value, count how many of your dice are equal to that value.
If the 2 counts are 2 and 3 (or 3 and 2), then you have your full house.

This looks like Yahtzee, so such an algorithm can be easily modified for three-of-a-kind, four-of-a-kind, and a Yahtzee.

Comment: Yup, it is. And those three functions work for me. It's just Full House and Small Straight